# Pyspark defined line split

Tags: split, pyspark

I am working with big log files where 1 message can be on several lines.

```
2015-08-07 00:01:16,886 [2100] DEBUG Dac.DacNet [(null)] - Get1ExpiredSession entry
2015-08-07 00:01:16,886 [2100] DEBUG Dac.DacNet [Service: Get1ExpiredSession
SPROC: Get1ExpiredSession]
2015-08-07 00:01:56,276 [4440] DEBUG axax.Global [(null)] - Application_BeginRequest - Load Balanced: True
2015-08-07 00:01:56,276 [4440] DEBUG axax.Global [(null)] - Application_BeginRequest - Load Balancer Secured: False
2015-08-07 00:01:56,292 [4440] DEBUG axax.Global [(null)] - Application_BeginRequest - Request Secured: False
2015-08-07 00:01:56,292 [4440] DEBUG axax.Global [(null)] - Application_BeginRequest - Skip Redirection: True
```

As you can see, the third line messsage ('SPROC: Get1ExpiredSession]') belongs to the previous one.

But when I read the files with `sc.textFile('/group/*')`, the lines are automatically split on `\n`

Is there a way to split on, for example, `re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')` or in opposite, do not split on line which doesn't start with date?

I am also OK if you can give me a solution when I can attach back the messages to the line they belong to.